# MySqlCommand Parameter not Working

Tags: .net, mysql

In the following code, used to get a list of products in a particular line, the command only returns results when I hard code (concatenate) `productLine` into the SQL.  The parameter substitution never happens.

```
            + "lineName = '@productLine' "                       
            + "and isVisible = 1 ";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, msc);
        adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@productLine", productLine);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        + "lineName = ?productLine "                       
        + "and isVisible = 1 ";
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, msc);
    adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("?productLine", productLine);
```

1. Remove the apostrophes (').
2. Change @ to ?, which is the prefix of parameters in MySql queries.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the apostrophes (spelling?). The ' around the parameter.  They should not be needed.

Comment: If they value is a string they are.

Comment: Had to mark back up since actually the poster is correct and Mr Stevenson-Leggett is mistaken

Comment: That is an important point about parameters. You don't have to worry about encapsulating strings or formatting dates and all that.

Answer (score 0):

like he said

```
+ "lineName = '@productLine' "
```

should be

```
+ "lineName = @productLine "
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct it never happens you have

- "lineName = '@productLine' "

try

- "lineName = @productLine " instead as @productLine will already be declared as a string type the quotes will be added secretly.  You however are actually passing the string @productLine and not the variable value.