# Input String was Not in a Correct Format

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, user-input

I'm new to creating applications using Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL. I am creating an application that adds the information to the database. But then when I click the add button, there is an error message which says **Input string was not in a correct format.** But I enter letters to the textbox and I used VarChar as the DataType. Now, I can't figure out what's the problem.

Code:

```
private void buttonaddcompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=payroll;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "insert into company(company_name, company_other_names, company_office_number, company_office_building, company_office_street, company_office_village, company_municipality_name, company_municipality_zipcode, company_province_name, company_province_zipcode, company_country_name, company_country_zipcode) values(?company_name, ?company_other_names, ?company_office_number, ?company_office_building, ?company_office_street, ?company_office_village, ?company_municipality_name, ?company_municipality_zipcode, ?company_province_name, ?company_province_zipcode, ?company_country_name, ?company_country_zipcode)";
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_other_names", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_office_number", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_office_building", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_office_street", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_office_village", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_municipality_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_municipality_zipcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_province_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_province_zipcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_country_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_country_zipcode", MySqlDbType.VarChar));
                command.Parameters["?company_name"].Value = addcompname.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_other_names"].Value = addcompothername.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_office_number"].Value = addoffnumber.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_office_building"].Value = addoffbuilding.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_office_street"].Value = addoffstreet.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_office_village"].Value = addoffvillage.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_municipality_name"].Value = addoffmunname.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_municipality_zipcode"].Value = addoffmunzipcode.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_province_name"].Value = addoffprovname.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_province_zipcode"].Value = addoffprovzipcode.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_country_name"].Value = addoffcountryname.Text;
                command.Parameters["?company_country_zipcode"].Value = addoffcountryzipcode.Text;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            }
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the FormatException]

Comment: Try getting rid of the @ signs in the lines where you add and set the parameters (but, leave them in the query).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySqlCommand Parameter not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250599/mysqlcommand-parameter-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but maybe a common way to fight such problems in a future. If I encounter such problems, I simplify it to minimal form. In your case this would be some thing like:

```
private void buttonaddcompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=payroll;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand com = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "insert into company(company_name, /* other fields here , */ company_country_zipcode) values(?company_name, 'company_other_names', /* other hardcoded fields here , */ 'company_country_zipcode')";
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?company_name", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            command.Parameters["?company_name"].Value = addcompname.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
        }
    }
}
```

this allows to narrow places there some typos can drive you crazy. Stick with simplified form until problem is resolved, so you can be sure that code logic is correct. Then return to full code version and see if it working. If not, then probably it's just typos.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no value assignment for parameter @company_province_zipcode?

Answer (score 1):

I believe MySQL parameters need to be prefixed with ? instead of @:

```
new MySqlParameter( "?company_name", ... )
command.Parameters["?company_name"].Value = ...
```

Edit: I read this somewhere, but I'm not sure of it myself.

Comment: I already did changed the '@' into '?'. But still with errors.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

You have at least one misspelling inside the field list of the insert.:

```
compnay_office_village
```

Comment: I already did changed the '@' into '?'. But still with errors.

Comment: thanks for that. But there is another error message which is "Unknown column 'company_country_zipcode' in 'field list'" and I tried to check if there are misspelled words, but I spelled it right. what might be the problem with this? Thanks

Comment: @sean:  That usually means that the field isn't in the table.  Make sure it's correctly spelled in your table definition.